# Datatable cannot get row index after search

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables

I have create a datatable and can get the row index of the data before any search action.

```
dataArray=[
   [1, "Name1"],       
   [2, "Name2"], , 
   [3, "Name23"], 
];


var table = $('#tblName').DataTable( {
             scrollY:        '40vh',
             "scrollX": true,
             scrollCollapse: true,
             paging:         false,
             responsive:true,
             data: dataArray,
           } );
$('#tblName tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected1') ) {
    }
    else 
    {
       $('#tblName tbody tr ').each(  function () {
          if ( $(this).hasClass('selected1') ) {
             $(this).removeClass('selected1');
           }
       } );
       $(this).addClass('selected1');
    }
} );
```

I want to get the row index to change the value of the `dataArray` . The following is the input text `searchName` to filter the datatable with keyword match with `dataArray` in column 1

```
$('#searchName').on( 'keyup', function () {
   table
   .columns( 1 )
   .search( this.value )
   .draw();
} );

$('#tblName tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
   $('#tblName tbody tr ').each(  function () {
       if ( $(this).hasClass('selected1') ) {
           var rowindex=$(this).closest('tr').index();
           var dataWareHouse = table.row( this ).columns(1).data();
           var selectedName = dataArray[0][rowindex];
           console.log(selectedName);
       }
    } );
} );
```

After filter the datatable with input text `searchName`, I cannot get the correct old row Index. For example input in `searchName`:

> 2

The datable will show only 2 row with Name of `Name2` and `Name23`,
However, when i click the first row, it show the `Name1`. The correct return data should be `Name2`

Comment: Have you tried to use API to get row index? `var rowindex = table.row(this).index()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't rely on DOM index when you are using search. Since some data will not be displayed due to filtering. But DataTable provide API method to get correct [indices](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()), [data](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()), etc.

```
$('#tblName tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
   $('#tblName tbody tr ').each(  function () {
       if ( $(this).hasClass('selected1') ) {
           var rowindex = table.row(this).index();
           var rowData = table.row(this).data();
           var selectedName = table.row(this)[0];
           var anotherWayToGetName = table.cell(rowIndex, 0).data();
           console.log(rowIndex, rowData, selectedName, anotherWayToGeName);
       }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It is work!! even in paginating, it also workable!!